# How do i extract jquery and react from main bundle to common.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I already solved that problem with `require.ensure` but my code is ugly with all this `reqiure.ensure`. All i really want is to extract `react-dom` and `jquery` into separate `common.js` file. But all i get is code duplication =/

Here is my webpack.config

```
context: __dirname+ "/resources/app",
entry: {
    main: './main.jsx',
    common: ["jquery","react","react-dom"]
},

progress: true,

output: {
    publicPath: "/js/",
    path: __dirname+"/public/js",
    filename: '[name].js',
    library:"[name]"
},
```

and here is my plugins:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: "common" }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
]


     Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   main.js  244 kB       0  [emitted]  main
 common.js  232 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  common
```

When I `import $ from 'jquery'` all jquery code adds to `main.jsx`

> `jquery` module just added to `main.js`, even it's already exists in in common.js

```
         Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  main.js  330 kB       0  [emitted]  main
 common.js  232 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  common
```

Comment: What happens if you add `minChunks: Infinity,` to the CommonsChunkPlugin options?

Comment: @Ambroos that's does not help either